# Freeing a component from Thread in Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have written a thread to check if there are any freeze in mainform. I am doing this because sometimes TWebbrowser freezes main UI. I think it is because of a javascript and i can not reproduce this problem.

What i need is to safely stop TWebbrowser's job. Actually it should be in a loop or waiting for something but it freezes somehow. Well what i need is to detect and kill the browser and recreate it.

This is how i detect the freeze:

```
bFreeze := SendMessageTimeout(hwn, WM_NULL, 0, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG OR SMTO_BLOCK, TIME_OUT, iRes) <= 0;
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are running the browser control from your program's main thread. Any attempt to forcibly terminate the browser thread will bring down your entire program. If you have code that can hang, and you wish to recover from that, then it is just not realistic to expect to run that code from your main thread.

Modern browsers deal with this problem by isolating each page in a distinct process. Then if that page hangs in some way, or crashes, the page process can be killed without impacting on the other pages open in the browser.

If you really want to have similar robustness you'll need to have a similar architecture. You might be tempted to think you can isolate a page in a thread within a single process but in practise this doesn't give sufficient isolation.

Perhaps a more tenable solution is to avoid the hang in the first place. Maybe you need to make sure that you are using the latest browser engine. Did you specify that in the browser feature emulation registry key?

Comment: Actually it never happened in my pc and i can never reproduce the problem. Once i have coded a seperate app and embedded it in my app. If it freeze, it freezez main app too. This is what i am trying to do but i think i will need to go back to seperate process as you recommended.

Comment: instead, i want to add TWebbrowser in an oleserver (exe) and i think it would be better. What do you think?

Comment: Btw, yes i did the emulation registry key thing

Comment: Embedding a window is liable to be just as bad. I think that modern browsers with multiple processes don't do that but use IPC mechanisms instead. I doubt that it is remotely tractable for you to replicate this though.